# How to install a module for drupal 9.1 via composer on EC2 instance of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drupal, composer-php, drupal-9

/home/ec2-user/ - I have the composer.json and composer.lock files under this path. The drupal 9.1 is also installed under this path. I have made composer global by putting the composer.phar file under /usr/local/bin

/home/ec2-user/drupal - While installing the modules via composer under this path, they are getting installed in the below folder,

/home/ec2-user/drupal/modules/contrib. But I can't view the modules in the drupal UI, under extend/modules section. This is specially required for 'phpmailer_smtp' module which requires the phpMailer library to be installed via the composer.

/home/ec2-user/drupal/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer - this is the path where the library is getting installed. Still on drupal, I'm unable to view the modules installed via composer on EC2. Can someone please help?

```
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.1",
    "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.3",
    "drupal/phpmailer_smtp": "2.0.2",
    "drupal/smtp": "^1.0"
},
"installer-paths": {
        "core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
    }
```

Comment: What is your exact question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem? "I can't view the modules in the drupal UI" - what does that mean? How is that problem related to Composer itself, or to [tag:amazon-web-services]?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my doubt, I'm unable to install 'phpmailer_smtp' module on drupal 9. On drupal, when I'm trying to install the module, it is showing an error, "Please install the PHPMailer library by executing 'composer update' in your site's root directory. (Currently using PHPMailer library version Missing)". I've run the cmd at /home/ec2-user/drupal/ but with no effect.